# How does Gatsby hide API-keys on the frontend

Tags: shopify, gatsby

So, I'm struggling to understand how Gatsby works. I'm using the https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/AlexanderProd/gatsby-shopify-starter/ which uses a Gatsby plugin called `gatsby-source-shopify`. The plugin takes two params: `shopName` and `accessToken`. It looks like this in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-shopify`,
  options: {
    // The domain name of your Shopify shop. This is required.
    shopName: process.env.SHOP_NAME,

    // An API access token to your Shopify shop. This is required.
    accessToken: process.env.SHOPIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  },
},
```

Will the access token be available for people to look at when I deploy the app? Do I need to use something like Serverless functions to hide my API keys, or is this fine. Any general explanation of how this works in Gatsby would be awesome.

Thanks Gatsby fam!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code shows, it uses `process.env.SHOP_NAME` where `SHOP_NAME`is the name of the [environment variable](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/). Those files are declared at the root of the project using some naming such as `.env.domain1.com`. In this file, you can store any desired variable to use it in your Gatsby configurations. When dealing with delicate variables (API keys, tokens, passwords, etc) it's recommended to use that way and ignore all `.env` files in your `.gitignore`.

When you trigger a command in Gatsby, you can pass it some variables, for example:

```
"develop": "GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV=domain1.com gatsby develop"
```

In this case, `GATSBY_ACTIVE_ENV` var will have `domain1.com` as a value. Then, in you `gataby-config.js`, when you can use environment variables (above `module.exports`):

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Then, you can create an environment file such as `.env.domain1.com` in your root project and store any desired variable:

```
SHOP_NAME: 12345
```

Taking into account the code you've provided if you run `develop` (with all I've explained) command it will take `SHOP_NAME` as 12345.

So, answering your question, **you won't have access to that tokens. You need to store them in your local machine and in your deploy server, not in your repository**.
From Gatsby docs:

> Please note that you shouldn’t commit .env.* files to your source
>   control and rather use options given by your Continuous Deployment
>   (CD) provider...

**Edit**: Thanks to @Hans Martin Henken for providing the following article about [Gatsby security](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-04-06-security-for-modern-web-frameworks/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess what I’m really asking, is: what if I make a query in GraphQL to get all products. Will my application fetch data from Shopify during runtime or is it all stored on my server and fetched “locally”? Does that question make sense?

Comment: When you run a `develop` command Gatsby uses all the configurations (such as you mentioned of Shopify) to download all the content from the APIs and generate static files, so when you use GraphQL queries, you are fetching all data previously downloaded (i.e: you are fetching local data). If you don't have API tokens, you won't be able to download it and you will see a prompt error in your console. I hope I have answered your question

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. I also found this article explaining security in Gatsby with greater detail. Feel free to include your last comment + this link in your answer if anyone else ever comes across this. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-04-06-security-for-modern-web-frameworks/

Comment: Thanks @HansMartinHanken. I've included the article in my answer. If I can do something else for you just tell me. If not, please validate the answer to close the topic.